# Flash media live encoder: Command line error on Windows server 2008, GUI works

Tags: streaming, windows-server-2008, fmle

I'm running Windows Server 2008 with a Blackmagic Decklink card. Everything works fine with the GUI but when I try to start from command line it exits with an unknown error.

Any ideas?

Note: I have the desktop experience enabled.

Comment: Could you elaborate? For example, what command are you running, and exactly what error message does it respond with?

Comment: That's part of the problem, it just claims a fatal exception in the log file. Session started is the last thing printed in the terminal. As for the command, it's just fmlecmd.

Comment: "Fri May 27 2011 13:35:58 : Session Started
Flash Media Live Encoder has experienced an unrecoverable exception. The details here may help to locate the problem. If the module listed is a third party driver, try updating or using a different driver. For reproducible problems within Flash Media Live Encoder itself, send this file to  support@adobe.com with a description of what you were doing when the exception occurred."

Comment: Update: This only happens with certain (most) aspect ratios...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was, apparently if the fmesessions.dat (C:\ProgramData\Adobe\Flash Media Live Encoder 3.2) gets large enough FMLEcmd.exe fails.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a [frequent problem that effects many FMLE users](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&biw=1160&bih=903&q=+site%3aforums.adobe.com+Session+Started+Flash+Media+Live+Encoder+has+experienced+an+unrecoverable+exception.). Common suggestions include:

- use the absolute [latest version of FMLE](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/flashmediaencoder/)
- update [DirectX](http://www.gamesforwindows.com/en-US/directx/)
- update all video and audio-related drivers
- remove/rename startup.xml from  "[volume]/Users/[user name]/AppData/Roaming/Adobe/Flash Media Live Encoder [version]/" so the program can get clean settings

There is also a small chance that tweaks to common security measures may help, such as [disabling Data Execution Protection for all but essential OS files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/875351) or exclude program directories in your anti-virus software (only if essential, of course!)

Comment: Thanks for that but unfortunately this seems to be a problem with the card driver. It crashes when I try to set any aspect except the default for the card. Yet only in command line mode. A bit weird.